# Does iPhone picker support HTML hidden Attribute?

Tags: html, iphone

I'm trying to hide one of the option tags by using hidden attribute.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp

```
<select>
   <option disabled hidden>Hidden</option>
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option>Option2</option>
</select>
```

However, it seems it does not work if the iPhone picker component.
I believe this is because of the iPhone picker component.

If it's true, how can I hide it?

(Note pics are BrowserStack emulator)

iPhone 
[image]

Android 
[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066953/css-hide-options-from-select-menu-on-iphone-safari

Comment: Thanks it works. But I want its tag to be placeholder like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box. If I use span tag, I cannot use its tag as placeholder.