# Change option in the list depenting on selection made in another list

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show/hide option in the list depending on the selection made in another list?

here is what I have:

```
<div data-repeater-item class="row">
    <select class="subcategory">
        <option value="1">Subcategory 1</option>
        <option value="2">Subcategory 2</option>
        <option value="3">Subcategory 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="tag_id">
        <option value="1" data-dynamic="1">Tag 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-dynamic="1">Tag 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-dynamic="1">Tag 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-dynamic="2">Tag 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-dynamic="2">Tag 5</option>
        <option value="6" data-dynamic="3">Tag 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div data-repeater-item class="row">
    <select class="subcategory">
        <option value="1">Subcategory 1</option>
        <option value="2">Subcategory 2</option>
        <option value="3">Subcategory 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="tag_id">
        <option value="1" data-dynamic="1">Tag 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-dynamic="1">Tag 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-dynamic="1">Tag 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-dynamic="2">Tag 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-dynamic="2">Tag 5</option>
        <option value="6" data-dynamic="3">Tag 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My JS looks like this:

```
    var tag_id = $('.tag_id option');
    $('.subcategory').change(function () {
        tag_id.hide();
        var op = $(this).closest('.subcategory').val();
        tag_id.closest('[data-dynamic="' + op + '"]').show();
    });
```

There are 2 problems that I am currently having:
1. if I make a selection in one list `subcategory` list, it changes options in the `tag_id` in both rows, but what I need it to be able to only make a change in the row in which I am changing the subcategory.
2. The rows can be added/removed, but at the moment when I add a new row, I can select a `subcategory`, but it does not have any effect on `tag_id`

Can you please help, I do not have much experience in jQuery/js

Answer (score 1):

`tag_id` have `options` from both `select` elements with class `.tag_id`. Instead get the sibling of selected `subcategory`. As well instead of `closest` use `filter`. Also, no need of `$(this).closest('.subcategory').val();` you can use directly `$(this).val()` to get the selected value.

```js
$('.subcategory').change(function() {
   const associatedTag =  $(this).siblings('select.tag_id');
   associatedTag.children().hide();
   const selectedSubCategory = $(this).val();
   associatedTag.children().filter('[data-dynamic="' + selectedSubCategory + 
  '"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-repeater-item class="row">
  <select class="subcategory">
    <option value="1">Subcategory 1</option>
    <option value="2">Subcategory 2</option>
    <option value="3">Subcategory 3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="tag_id">
    <option value="1" data-dynamic="1">Tag 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-dynamic="1">Tag 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-dynamic="1">Tag 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-dynamic="2">Tag 4</option>
    <option value="5" data-dynamic="2">Tag 5</option>
    <option value="6" data-dynamic="3">Tag 6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div data-repeater-item class="row">
  <select class="subcategory">
    <option value="1">Subcategory 1</option>
    <option value="2">Subcategory 2</option>
    <option value="3">Subcategory 3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="tag_id">
    <option value="1" data-dynamic="1">Tag 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-dynamic="1">Tag 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-dynamic="1">Tag 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-dynamic="2">Tag 4</option>
    <option value="5" data-dynamic="2">Tag 5</option>
    <option value="6" data-dynamic="3">Tag 6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your quick response, but for some reason, it does not work as expected, even in the snippet. rows should not depend on one another, so if I select a subcategory in the first row the tag selection of the second row should not be affected. Also the `data-dynamic` is the ID of subcategory

Comment: Thank, now it works here as expected, but for some reason, I am having trouble implementing it. It still does not run on my site, let me figure it out

Comment: it looks like the mistake is in the following line `const associatedTag = $(this).siblings('select.tag_id');`. I do not get any errors in the console, but no change is happening in the `tag_id`. Also, when I replace `const $(this).siblings('select.tag_id');` with `$('.tag_id')` it works, but changes `tag_id` options in select in all rows

Comment: @AlexB - It seems like $(this) is referring to something else.  Have you used arrow function i:e `$('.subcategory').change(() => {})`? Can you post your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196275/discussion-between-randomsoul-and-alexb).

Answer (score 0):

In Generall, what you want to achive isn't possible in IE11 and Safari.
They are blocking setting options to display none.

You should set the option attribute disabled and remove it, if an option should be visible/usable. Use css instead of jquery to the options.

```
select option:disabled {
  display:none;
}
```

If you want to remove them from the selection you have to remove them from the html. See here for reference [CSS - Hide Options From Select Menu on iPhone & Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066953/css-hide-options-from-select-menu-on-iphone-safari)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not concerned with IE11 as this part is only in the admin panel