# Safari Dropdown Hide Workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, dropdown

I'm currently facing an issue with hiding specific options from a dropdown in Safari on iOS for our Magento application. After researching potential solutions, I found a hack that involves wrapping the options in a  element. Here's the code I've tried:

```
Hide for iOS with jQuery:
if (!($(this).parent().is('span'))) $(this).wrap('<span>');

Unhide for iOS with jQuery:
if ($(this).parent().is('span')) $(this).unwrap();
```

This hack successfully hides the desired options; however, it interferes with other JavaScript handlers in our Magento application, causing them to malfunction.

Upon further investigation, I discovered a comment suggesting that Safari uses an overlay for dropdowns and that the recommended approach is to remove the options completely. However, this approach is not feasible for us since we need to show back the hidden options based on other actions.

I also came across another comment proposing an alternative solution. It suggests creating a hidden select with all the options and cloning only the relevant ones to the visible select. This way, we can display the desired options while keeping a record of the other options in a hidden list. Unfortunately, this approach poses challenges due to the multiple dependencies among our dropdowns.

Considering these circumstances, I wanted to seek your expertise and experiences regarding this issue. Have any of you encountered a similar situation and found a reliable solution that effectively hides dropdown options in Safari on iOS without conflicting with other JavaScript code? I would greatly appreciate any insights, alternative approaches, or potential workarounds you may have to offer.

Comment: reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066953/css-hide-options-from-select-menu-on-iphone-safari